# Filter column by row value PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to write a DAX function to find the maximum value in one column based on a condition in another, but have this condition change dynamically based on the row value.

With this code:

```
CALCULATE(MAX(RankOfArea[count]),filter(RankOfArea,RankOfArea[Line]="Pic"))
```

I get this table:

```
count |  Line  |  Max
7220  | Pic    |  7220
283   | Dis    |  7220
3557  | Pic    |  7220
317   | Met    |  7220
500   | Met    |  7220
```

And I'd like this result:

```
count |  Line  |  Max
7220  | Pic    |  7220
283   | Dis    |  283
3557  | Pic    |  7220
317   | Met    |  500
500   | Met    |  500
```

Of course I have to remove the ="Pic", but not sure what to replace it with? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this for a calculated column.

---

One way is to remove all row context and explicitly define your condition:

```
  Max = CALCULATE(MAX(RankOfArea[Count]),
                ALL(RankOfArea),
                RankOfArea[Line] = EARLIER(RankOfArea[Line]))
```

(The `EARLIER` function refers to the earlier row context.)

---

Another way is to remove just the `[Count]` row context:

```
  Max = CALCULATE(MAX(RankOfArea[Count]), ALL(RankOfArea[Count])
```

In this case, since there are only two columns, this is equivalent to removing all row context except for the `[Line]` value:

```
  Max = CALCULATE(MAX(RankOfArea[Count]), ALLEXCEPT(RankOfArea, RankOfArea[Line]))
```

I recommend this latter approach in case your table acquires more columns.

Comment: Thanks - both do the trick. I think I need to do some more reading around CALCULATE and contexts as the latter two solutions don't make sense to me. Think I still have an Excel mindset when looking at these things..